# Charge a Tokenized Credit Card

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, authorize.net

I'm using Authorize.net. I don't want send user card information in each payment. I found this:

[Charge a tokenized credit card](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#payment-transactions-charge-a-tokenized-credit-card)

But how could I get card token information from token service and fill these fields?

```
<cardNumber>5424000000000015</cardNumber>
<expirationDate>1220</expirationDate>
<cryptogram>EjRWeJASNFZ4kBI0VniQEjRWeJA=</cryptogram>
<tokenType>chasepay</tokenType>
<tokenRequestorID>123456789AB</tokenRequestorID>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this method requires that your processor support payment network tokenization and the token must have been issued by a certified token provider. For example, see
[https://developer.visa.com/products/vts/guides](https://developer.visa.com/capabilities/vts/docs) for details on Visa Token Service.

You're probably looking for [customer profiles](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#customer-profiles) which allows you to securely store card data for future use.  Or you can use the new [Accept.js Javascript library](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html) to avoid sending card data through your servers.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer their question

Answer (score 0):

You can use authorize.net Customer Information Manager (CIM) service to avoid entering card details every time by the user. CIM creates the payment profiles for every user first time when he/she enters the card details and in response givest the payment profile id that you can use to charge the credit card latter on on next payment.
You can explore the language and sample code in below link.

http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/#customer-profiles

https://github.com/AuthorizeNet

Thanks